# Libgdx Table Layout Logical table not Positioning Correctly

Tags: libgdx

I wants to store a scrollpane in a table. However, the positioning of the images are not as expected.[image]

I have look through [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table), but has no clue on solving my problem.

The blue box (logical table) of the scrollpane and scrolldetails table is not at the right position. Please help.

My codes goes as below:

```
 scrollDetails = new Table();
    scrollDetails.setBackground(skin.getDrawable("gameSelectionBox1"));
    scrollDetails.setDebug(true);
    Button b = new Button(skin,"arithmetic");
    scrollDetails.add(b);
    scrollDetails.pack();

    sp = new ScrollPane(scrollDetails);
    sp.setOverscroll(false,true);
    sp.pack();
    sp.setDebug(true);

    table = new Table();

    table.setFillParent(true);
    table.bottom().padBottom(100).add(sp).align(Align.center);
    table.setDebug(true);
    table.pack();

//tried but has no effect
    //t.setPosition(0,100);
    //sp.setPosition(0,550);
    //tt.setPosition(0,100);

    stage.addActor(tt);
```

Answer (score 0):

setFillParent() does not work correctly inside a ScrollPane. Remove the line and it will work as intended.